# If $A$ and $D$ are simply connected subspaces with $A \cap D \neq ø$ then $A \cup D$ is also simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

They ask me to decide if it is true or false the next sentence:

- If $A$ and $D$ are simply connected subspaces with $A \cap D \neq ø$ then $A \cup D$ is also simply connected.

Well my answer is:

I think it is true because if $A \cap D \neq ø$ then the space $A \cup D$ is path connected so the first statement of the definition of simply connected is OK, and then to prove that the fundamental group of $A \cup D$ is the trivial one I write that as long as it is path connected if we prove that for one point of $A \cup D$ the fundamental group is the trivial it will be for every point. So if you take any path ($\delta$) that is contain in $A \cup D$ it will be on the class of the constant path ($C_p$) because we don't have any obstacles or missing points so the homotopy define as $H(s,t) = (1-s) \cdot \delta$ + $s \cdot C_p$.
And that's all, I don't know if it is right or not because I see one answer from previous years and it says it is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two halves of a circle are simply connected but not the circle. Another way to say that: a circle can be viewed as the union of two simply connected intervals which intersect in two points. For example take the circle $C$ centered at $0$ of radius $1$ in the plane, $I_1=\{(x,y)\in C, x\geq 0\}, I_2=\{(x,y)\in C, x\leq 0\}$.

Comment: But why can we affirm that the circle $C$ = $I_1 \cup I_2$ is not simply connected? Is path connected but what is the path that hasn't an homotopy with the constant path?

Comment: @Alvaro: The circle is a counterexample.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798923/why-is-a-circle-not-simply-connected

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why the fundamental group of the circle isn't the trivial
Because for $S^1$ I know that the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $S^1$ is the circle.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking that with circle it reffers to $B(0,1)$ instead of to the circunference.

Comment: @Alvaro in topology we typically refer to the space $\mathbb{D}^2 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\ |\ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ as a "disk" or "ball", and the "circle" is $S^1 = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\ |\ x^2 + y^2 =1\}$ which is the boundary of the disk.

Comment: It is even false if we assume that $A \cap D$ is a singleton. Take $A$ = closed upper half circle and $D$ = closed upper half circle minus one of its endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

To help you visualize T.Aristide answer, think of a simply connected space as something with no hole, that is something you cannot hang on a needle.

If you take a sheet of paper and punch a hole in it, then it is no more simply connected.

But now if you cut this paper along a line that passes through the hole, both sheets obtained have no holes, they have only a curvy edge (half circle) in some area but you cannot hang the pieces of paper on a needle, they fall off.

So despite both half are simply connected, the union is not.